# I did null safety migration on my flutter poject but it show language vesion error

Tags: flutter, dart, migrate, dart-null-safety

I created an recipe app on flutter i got some error build function return null so i do null safety but thats also shows an error like this

**Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.12 or higher.**

could you please someone help me

pubspec.yaml

```yaml
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3

dev_dependencies:
  firebase_auth: ^1.4.1
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^1.3.0
  provider: ^5.0.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.7
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
  http: ^0.13.3
  cloud_firestore: ^2.2.2


# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - asserts/images/
    #- images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
```

Comment: Please provide the content of `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: Hi please check below the question

Comment: If you are sure you have migrated your project to null safety, you need to `sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"` to `sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"` or `sdk: ">=2.13.0 <3.0.0"`.

Comment: Yes it's worked but thank you so much but I use document snapshot to display data in the widgets it makes so many errors is any possibility to change it